# How to repetitive function while holding QPushButton?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I have following code:

```
void MainWindow::OnClicked()
{
     otesanek->setPos(otesanek->pos().x() + 5,otesanek->pos().y());
}

connect(right, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnClicked()));
```

*otesanek* is QGraphicsItem in QGraphicsScene and *right* is QPushButton in the same scene

My target: 
By holding the button (right) the item moves right over 5 pix repeatedly untill not holding the button.

This code doing:
I have to click again and again to move over 5 pix and again 5 pix

I tried to make this with OnPressed function, but I got no result.

Hope you understand my problem
Thanks for answers :-)

Comment: did you try to connect your object with `QAbstractButton::pressed()` signal instead of `clicked()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `QTimer` to call a slot in your class repeatedly and use the `MousePress` and `MouseRelease` events to start and stop the `QTimer`

Very basic example:

**MyGraphicsView.h**

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QTimer>

class MyGraphicsView: public QGraphicsView
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  MyGraphicsView() {}
  MyGraphicsView( QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MyGraphicsView() {};

public slots:
  void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event );
  void mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent * event );
  void moveItem();

private:
  QGraphicsEllipseItem *item;
  QTimer *timer;
};
```

**MyGraphicsView.cpp**

```
#include "MyGraphicsView.h"

MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView( QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsView(scene,parent)
{
  item = new QGraphicsEllipseItem( 0, this->scene() );
  item->setRect( -50.0, -50.0, 100.0, 100.0 );
  item->setFlag( QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable );
  timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT( moveItem() ) );
}


void MyGraphicsView::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent *  )
{
  timer->start(10);
}

void MyGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent( QMouseEvent * )
{
  timer->stop();
}

void MyGraphicsView::moveItem()
{
  item->setPos(item->pos().x() + 5,item->pos().y());
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyGraphicsView.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QGraphicsScene scene;
  scene.setSceneRect( -100.0, -100.0, 200.0, 200.0 );

  MyGraphicsView view( &scene );
  view.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Here the delay between two repetitions is 10 ms which you can adjust to your liking. I did not check explicitly which mouse button is pressed, but this you can do by calling `QMouseEvent::button ()` and compare it to the `Qt::MouseButton` enum.

Does this help?